# arc.describe file name not working

Tags: arcpy

I have multiple shapefiles in a folder which I am trying to compare with same named features in geodatabase. I want to first clip within an area polygon and then copy and overwrite the features in the geodatabase. So far the describe for shapefile names isn't working;

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy

# Set workspace

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
shpFile = arcpy.env.workspace
arcpy.AddMessage("\n")

shpName = arcpy.Describe(shpFile).baseName
featureName = arcpy.Describe(geoPath).baseName

# Count the number of shapefiles clipped
count1 = 0
# Count the number of feature classes being copied
count2 = 0

try:
 # Loop through shapefiles and clip to region
 for shp in shpFile:
     if shpName == featureName:
         arcpy.AddMessage(shpFile)
         arcpy.Clip_analysis (shpFile, clipRegion, outFc, "", "", "")
         count1 += 1
         # Copy clipped shapefile into file geodatabase
         arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(outFc, geoPath + "\\" + shpName)
         count1 += 1
     else:
         arcpy.AddMessage("Error: Shapefile/s not clipped and copied to file geodatabase ")
```

Comment: What? your workspace shouldn't have brackets and describe has no .file property.. I think you mean baseName. The geoPath is not the path to a geodatabase, but more likely the folder that it sits in. You will need to iterate your feature classes at some stage from arcpy.listFeatureClasses. Can you give us more of an idea of how your data is laid out in a folder/database/catalog sense please.

Comment: Oh, I had baseName first but changed it :(. the folder currently has a shapefile called parcel.shp, and the geodatabase has a feature call U:\\NRM_Base_Data\\Boundary\\parcel.

Comment: There's no geodatabase in U:\\NRM_Base_Data\\Boundary\\parcel, is it in that folder? (have you got extensions turned off in windows explorer?)

Comment: Script run ok with baseName change, but now printing message in else statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you have your extensions turned off and the database is U:\NRM_Base_Data.mdb.. on that basis:

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy

# Set workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\mwisniewski\\My Documents\\DPIPWE"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
clipRegion = "?????" # what is your clipRegion?
# Count the number of shapefiles clipped
count1 = 0
# Count the number of feature classes being copied
count2 = 0

# get a list of all the shapefiles in this folder
AllShapeFiles = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for shpFile in AllShapeFiles:
    # go through them one by one
    shpFile = arcpy.env.workspace
    arcpy.AddMessage("\n")

    # Location file geodatabase to update feature classes
    geoPath = "U:\\NRM_Base_Data.mdb\\Boundary"

    # Local variables
    shpName = arcpy.Describe(shpFile).baseName
    if arcpy.Exists(geoPath + "\\" shpName):
        #then it exists in the database
        arcpy.AddMessage(shpFile)
        # clip and overwrite to the database
        arcpy.Clip_analysis (shpFile, clipRegion, geoPath + "\\" shpName)
        count1 += 1
    else:
        arcpy.AddMessage("Error: Shapefile/s not clipped and copied to file geodatabase ")
```

Comment: My extensions turned off with .gdb. Michael, sometimes I will receive shapefiles that will need to go into different Feature Datasets in the NRM_Base_Data geodatabase. How can I handle this as I have workspace set for folder containing the shapefiles?

Comment: You will probably need to use a dictionary, getting all the names in the database and their full path... I would use arcpy.walk() to get all the feature classes in the database, but that's a separate question.

Comment: Michael, I tried your script but couldn't fix the syntax error for shpName in; if arcpy.Exists(geoPath + "\\" shpName). I have updated my original script which is sort of working but only prints out the else: arcpy.AddMessage . Is my trouble I am trying to match name of parcel.shp with just parcel feature class?

Comment: Rather than having a question of ever expanding scope, which is a poor fit for our focussed Q&A format, I recommend that you accept this answer, and start a new question which has a code snippet that illustrates where you are stuck, and works up until that point.