# Python code that uses arcpy.describe skips if statement?

Tags: arcpy

I have multiple shapefiles in a folder which I am trying to compare with same named features in geodatabase.

I want to first clip them within a polygon and then copy and overwrite the features in the geodatabase.

My script is currently skipping the if statement (no geoprocessing) and printing the else statement.

```
# Set workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\mwisniewski\\My Documents\\DPIPWE"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
shpFile = arcpy.env.workspace
arcpy.AddMessage("\n")

# Location file geodatabase to update feature classes
geoPath = "U:\\NRM_Base_Data.gdb"

# Local variables
clipRegion = "U:\\Boundary\\NRM_Regions\\DPIPWE_NRMRegionBoundary_Tas_Unk.gdb\\Cradle_Coast_NRM_Region"
shpName = arcpy.Describe(shpFile).baseName
featureName = arcpy.Describe(geoPath).baseName
outFc = "" 

shpName = arcpy.Describe(shpFile).baseName
featureName = arcpy.Describe(geoPath).baseName
outFc = ""

# Count the number of shapefiles clipped
count1 = 0
# Count the number of feature classes being copied
count2 = 0

try:
 # Loop through shapefiles and clip to NRM region
 for shp in shpFile:
     if shpName == featureName:
         arcpy.AddMessage(shpFile)
         arcpy.Clip_analysis (shpFile, clipRegion, outFc, "", "", "")
         count1 += 1
         # Copy clipped shapefile into file geodatabase
         arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(outFc, geoPath + "\\" + shpName)
         count1 += 1
     else:
         arcpy.AddMessage("Error: Shapefile/s not clipped and copied to file geodatabase ")
```

Comment: Would you be able to **edit** your question to include the values of shpFile and geoPath, please?  I would also recommend removing your try/except while you are trying to debug this code snippet.

Comment: Could you print the shpName and featureName variables and see what they contain?

Comment: It would appear that you are trying to implement the example in the answer to [your other question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152159/arc-describe-file-name-not-working). Take a closer look...as it is, you are likely iterating over a string (`shpFile`) which will produce individual characters which are never actually used for comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the best way to do this is with a dictionary, this is an object that stores values like `Key,Value` (not an easy python concept so bear with me).. There are some tutorials that describe dictionaries and what they can do [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) and [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-python).

First thing we need to do is go through the 'to' database finding all the feature classes and storing their full path; note that in a single database all names *must* be unique, this approach wouldn't necessarily work for a folder tree where names are not guaranteed to be unique.

```
WSdict = {} # new empty directory..

# put all the names into a dictonary with a key of the name
for (path, dir, datasets) in arcpy.da.Walk(InGDB,datatype="FeatureClass"):
    for thisDS in datasets:
        WSdict[thisDS.upper()] = os.path.join(path,thisDS) # key is upper case to avoid case problems later
```

This creates a dictonary like:

```
{ "FEATURECLASS1":"c:\\full\\path.gdb\\FeatureClass1",
"FEATURECLASS2":"c:\\full\\path.gdb\\FeatureClass2",
"FEATURECLASS3":"c:\\full\\path.gdb\\dataset\\FeatureClass3" }
```

which when you ask for "FeatureClass1" will return "c:\full\path.gdb\FeatureClass1"... nice! That way you can have your base name and also your full path, but wait, it gets cooler! you can now ask *do you have "FEATURECLASS1"*? by using `WSdict.has_key("FEATURECLASS1")` to find out if the shape file is matched in the geodatabase.

Now the whole thing together:

```
import os, sys, arcpy

InGDB = sys.argv[1]
InShpFolder = sys.argv[2]

WSdict = {} # empty dictionary

# put all the names into a dictonary with a key of the name
for (path, dir, datasets) in arcpy.da.Walk(InGDB,datatype="FeatureClass"):
    for thisDS in datasets:
        WSdict[thisDS.upper()] = os.path.join(path,thisDS) # key is upper case to avoid case problems later

arcpy.env.workspace = InShpFolder
for thisFC in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
    thisName,thisExt = os.path.splitext(thisFC) # get the shapefile name without extension (base name)

    if WSdict.has_key(thisName.upper()):
        # the shapefile is found in the database..
        shpFull = os.path.join(InShpFolder,thisFC)# full path of shape file
        gdbFull = WSdict[thisName.upper()]        # get the path from the dictionary
        print("Found shapefile")
        print(shpFull + " -> " + gdbFull)
```

Comment: Sorry, was away sick, have edited question to include the values of shpFile and geoPath in case someone has another answer.

Comment: I had a sick day last week too. Replace sys.argv[n] with your hard paths.. the sys.argv is for putting the script into a toolbox. I tested this code by exporting a geodatabase to shapefile and then changing a few names (in both) and it worked just fine for me. All you need to do is incorporate your clip/copy into the loop and fix the paths and it's right to go.

Comment: Awesome Michael, I will incorporate the clip/copy. Thanks a lot for your help.