# Confusing results from script that uses arcpy.clip analysis?

Tags: arcpy

Following on from previous question [Python code that uses arcpy.describe skips if statement?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152166/python-code-that-uses-arcpy-describe-skips-if-statement), I have now attempted to include clip analysis and this is my result;

[image]

I am confused as to what is happening, as I am using .bdyseg.shp which is also in the file geodatabase for comparison and updating. Here is my code with the clip analysis in it;

```
# Import arcpy module
import os, sys, arcpy

InGDB = "C:\\Users\\mwisniewski\\My Documents\\NRM_Base_Data.gdb"
InShpFolder = "C:\\Users\\mwisniewski\\My Documents\\DPIPWE"

WSdict = {} # empty dictionary

# Local variables
clipRegion = "U:\\Boundary\\NRM_Regions\\DPIPWE_NRMRegionBoundary_Tas_Unk.gdb\\Cradle_Coast_NRM_Region"
outFc = ""

# Count the number of shapefiles clipped
count1 = 0
# Count the number of feature classes being copied
count2 = 0

# put all the names into a dictonary with a key of the name
for (path, dir, datasets) in arcpy.da.Walk(InGDB,datatype="FeatureClass"):
    for thisDS in datasets:
        WSdict[thisDS.lower()] = os.path.join(path,thisDS) # key is upper case to avoid case problems later

arcpy.env.workspace = InShpFolder
try:
 for thisFC in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
     thisName,thisExt = os.path.splitext(thisFC) # get the shapefile name without extension (base name)

     if WSdict.has_key(thisName.lower()):
         # the shapefile is found in the database..
        shpFull = os.path.join(InShpFolder,thisFC)# full path of shape file
        gdbFull = WSdict[thisName.lower()]        # get the path from the dictionary
        arcpy.AddMessage(shpFile)
        arcpy.Clip_analysis(InShpFolder, clipRegion, outFc, "", "", "")
        count1 += 1
        # Copy clipped shapefile into file geodatabase
        arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(outFc, InGDB + InShpFolder)
        count1 += 1
     else:
        arcpy.AddMessage("Error: Shapefile/s not clipped and copied to file geodatabase")

# Print message for shapefile name clipped 
arcpy.AddMessage("\n" "The above {0} shapefiles have been clipped to: {1} and saved in {2}" "\n".format(count1, InShpFolder, InGDB))

# Return any errors   
except:
    arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.GetMessages())
```

Comment: I can't believe I'm saying this but, can we get *all* the code in the question please. The problem is probably occurring before the code block shown. Shouldn't it be arcpy.Clip_analysis(shpFull , clipRegion, gdbFull )? You can't clip a folder and outFc, shpFile have no value (in this code).

Comment: Michael, I was asked by PolyGeo to not include all the code before and only a snippet of what I think is in question.

Comment: Original question updated to include entire script.

Comment: That's what makes this an interesting and somewhat different case.. the important variables aren't set here so we need to go further back to see what their values are.

Comment: I just noticed my name mentioned here and although I cannot locate the precise comment I made, I am pretty sure that I would have said to include a snippet of code that ***works*** up to the point where you are stuck.  If any variables are not being set within a snippet that uses them then you need to always provide us with one or two realistic values - otherwise the code snippet will not work.  Remember that GIS SE is not a code debugging service - but we are happy to help with places that you are stuck within code snippets.

Comment: PolyGeo, that sounds about right. My problem is I'm not sure where in the code it is falling over.

Comment: In order to become able to determine that I strongly recommend reviewing [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Put more simply, start a new script, copy a line or two (or at least very few) from your code at a time, and keep testing it until it breaks or starts to give unexpected results, then investigate that point in the test code (with our help if needed).  Fix it there and it generally becomes simple to fix in your full code which we should never have to see.

Comment: The script was going well until I added in the arcpy.Clip_analysis().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are remnant variables that have no value, as I remember the task you're trying to replace only the gdb feature classes that have new shapefiles:

```
# Import arcpy module
import os, sys, arcpy

InGDB = "C:\\Users\\mwisniewski\\My Documents\\NRM_Base_Data.gdb" # this isn't the path in your question
InShpFolder = "C:\\Users\\mwisniewski\\My Documents\\DPIPWE"

WSdict = {} # empty dictionary

# Local variables
clipRegion = "D:\Testing\TestMe\New_Shapefile.shp"
#outFc = "" # not used in this script

count1 = 0 # Count the number of shapefiles clipped
count2 = 0 # Count the number of feature classes being copied

# put all the names into a dictonary with a key of the name
for (path, dir, datasets) in arcpy.da.Walk(InGDB,datatype="FeatureClass"):
    for thisDS in datasets:
        WSdict[thisDS.lower()] = os.path.join(path,thisDS) # key is upper case to avoid case problems later

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = InShpFolder
try:
    for thisFC in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
        thisName,thisExt = os.path.splitext(thisFC) # get the shapefile name without extension (base name)
        if WSdict.has_key(thisName.lower()):
            print("Clipping " + thisFC)
            # the shapefile is found in the database..
            shpFull = os.path.join(InShpFolder,thisFC)# full path of shape file
            gdbFull = WSdict[thisName.lower()]        # get the path from the dictionary
            # arcpy.AddMessage(shpFile) # no value
            # clip directly into the geodatabase
            arcpy.Clip_analysis(shpFull, clipRegion, gdbFull)
            count1 += 1
            # Copy clipped shapefile into file geodatabase
            #arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(outFc, InGDB + InShpFolder)
            # count1 += 1 # don't need to do this twice
        else:
            arcpy.AddMessage("Error: Shapefile/s not clipped and copied to file geodatabase ")

    # Print message for shapefile name clipped 
    arcpy.AddMessage("The above {0} shapefiles have been clipped to: {1} and saved in {2}" "\n".format(count1, InShpFolder, InGDB))

    # Return any errors   
except:
    arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.GetMessages())
```

By turning on `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput` you will overwrite the existing gdb feature class with the clipped shapefile.

Comment: Michael, you are correct I changed the original geodatabase path because I am currently testing before I use it on the real dataset. I used to have outFc in the very first question which came out of the model builder script. Okay so I was lost on the process with removing outFc and inserting overwriteOutput. Having tested you answer, I have no luck unfortunately.

Comment: Any error messages? Check the indenting, it's been copy-pasted a few times so the indenting may be a bit off.

Comment: No identation errors in IDLE, and no printed errors, same print message as mine above. I have deleted a couple of features in the bdyseg.shp to see that this script works spatially when it gets clipped and copied to geodatabase. No success just yet.

Comment: I fixed the indent at arcpy.AddMessage("\n"....... and removed your valid comments

Comment: Indenting fixed.. look at line after # Print message for shapefile name clipped, this was tripping it out with no message. Also the syntax on that line was incorrect, get rid of the first "\n". That could also put it out of alignment with the for statement which is only indented by 1 space. This is why I use tabs!

Comment: Shouldnt the line for '# Print message for shapefile name clipped' be only 1 indent not 2?

Comment: No, it's a comment. Comments are *completely* ignored by the scripting interpreter so their indent level *really* doesn't matter.. that's why you can put them after if (condition): # comment without affecting your flow control. Just be careful if you're uncommenting a line.

Comment: Sorry Michael I was referring to the arcpy.message under the Print message comment.

Comment: Yes, it should be indented to the same level as *for*. It's not important whether it's 1, 2, 3 or 100 spaces it only matters that it's consistent. I use tabs (tabs and spaces in C); the tab/space(s) argument has been going on for as long as there has been programming languages so I don't want to enter into that argument... with python it is **vital** that the indenting is consistent. arcpy.GetMessages does not get error messages from python errors, only ArcGis errors, so if the indent is inconsistent the catch: will print an empty line, which is something to be aware of.

Comment: Same error in python with 'print' as message above in original question using arcpy.AddMessage. Confused with if statement using clip, if its not successful shouldn't it be going to except and printing that message?

Comment: I have edited it with tabs to the correct indent level, try copying again. arcpy.GetMessages() does not print python errors, only ArcGis errors, so if there's a problem with the python portion of the code your arcpy error is '' as no *arcpy* error has occured. This code works well for me running from command line... if you can't get it to work on your end there might be some subtle differences in your setup that I can't see or a locking situation (that does raise an error message) or slight spelling differences between your shapefiles and feature classes.

Comment: Michael, still no success, the image I posted is my setup, basically using custom Arctoolbox to run script. No locking occuring and I double check names of file and feature class which match.

Comment: The catalog path is c:\users\..\Documents\.. but the script is c:\users\..\my documents\.. are you sure your path is right?

Comment: Bloody Windows!!!! Good pickup, script all working now, big thanks Michael.